# Why has the list of close voters been removed?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, vote-to-close

A recent update to SE has removed the list of close voters on closed questions. Because of this, it can no longer be determined who closed it without stepping into `/revisions`. The information even seems to be missing from `/timeline`.

Being able to see who voted to close allows us to see if it was a community or moderator action. Without this, we lose transparency. Can we please have it back?

Comment: I hope that it is just a bug. only on meta yet so far I seen.

Comment: sorry about the noise and pointless, but I just wanted to make sure people can see its fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug, deploying a fix right now ....

Comment: Have you finished deploying? If so, I would need to do another bug report about another case.

Comment: yeah I can see something weird is going on ... fixing